# SQL if the case is true select the columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure this logic out. I have some project data I need to write a T-SQL statement for.

Essentially I have people who are marking a  "final task" in their project as complete but they have tasks above it that are not complete so in the executive dashboard they show the project as complete but when the execs look at the calculation they see not 100% but maybe 90%. Obviously people are trying to game the system by marking the "Go live Complete" task as 100% when they are not done. I need a query so I can see if they have marked Go live complete as 100% I need to see any other tasks that are not 100%.

There is a complicating factor - We have multiple projects so when I look at any other tasks not being 100% it needs to be only for that project.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN TaskName = 'Go Live Complete' 
            AND TaskPercentCompleted = '100' 
            AND ***'any other tasks are not 100% for that project'*** 
         THEN ***'Show me  the columns below'***
        {ProjectName]
       ,[SMO Programs]
      ,[ProjectUID]
      ,[Project Manager Name]
      ,[TaskUID]
      ,[ParentTaskUID]
      ,[TaskName]
      ,[TaskIndex]
      ,[TaskOutlineLevel]
      ,[Milestone Significance Level]
      ,[TaskOutlineNumber]
      ,[TaskStartDate]
      ,[TaskFinishDate]
      ,[TaskPercentCompleted]
      ,[EPRIDTaskName],
FROM 
    [ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[SMO_ALL_MTP_Tasks]
```

Comment: How do you know if the other tasks are not 100%?

Comment: ok with your edit, why not just put all your criteria in a WHERE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work... hard to tell without more info

```
WITH BADTASKS AS
(
  SELECT ProjctName, TaskName, SMO Programs, ProjectUID, [Project Manager Name], TaskUID, ParentTaskUID, TaskName, TaskIndex, TaskOutlineLevel, [Milestone Significance Level],
         TaskOutlineNumber, TaskStartDate, TaskFinishDate, TaskPercentCompleted, EPRIDTaskName
  FROM ProjectWebApp.dbo.SMO_ALL_MTP_Tasks
  WHERE TaskPercentCompleted != '100'
)
SELECT DONE.TaskName, DONE.TaskPercentCompleted, BADTASKS.*
FROM SMO_ALL_MTP_Tasks DONE
LEFT JOIN BADTASKS ON ALL.ProjectName = BADTASKS.ProjectName
WHERE DONE.TaskName = 'Go Live Complete' AND DONE.TaskPercentCompleted = '100'
```

Comment: This got me 90% of the way there and I was able to finish it up!  Thanks! Will mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
   WITH BADTASKS AS
(
  SELECT ProjectName, TaskName, [SMO Programs], [ProjectUID], [Project Manager Name], TaskUID, ParentTaskUID, TaskIndex, TaskOutlineLevel, [Milestone Significance Level],
         TaskOutlineNumber, TaskStartDate, TaskFinishDate, TaskPercentCompleted, EPRIDTaskName, EPRID
  FROM ProjectWebApp.dbo.SMO_ALL_MTP_Tasks
  WHERE TaskPercentCompleted != '100' AND TaskFinishDate < '2015-08-25 23:00:00.000'
)
SELECT DONE.TaskName, DONE.TaskPercentCompleted, BADTASKS.*
FROM ProjectWebApp.dbo.SMO_ALL_MTP_Tasks DONE
inner JOIN BADTASKS ON (
 done.ProjectName = BADTASKS.ProjectName AND
 substring(done.TaskOutlineNumber, 1, len(done.TaskOutlineNumber) - charindex('.', reverse(done.TaskOutlineNumber))) = substring(badTasks.TaskOutlineNumber, 1, len(badtasks.TaskOutlineNumber) - charindex('.', reverse(badtasks.TaskOutlineNumber)))
 )
WHERE DONE.TaskName = 'Go Live Complete' AND DONE.TaskPercentCompleted = '100' AND done.TaskFinishDate < '2015-08-25 23:00:00.000'
```